# Spring не распознает JSP шаблон

Tags: java, spring, jsp

При попытке перейти по пути, указанному в контроллере - выдаётся 404 ошибка.
В качестве имени отображения возвращается 'admin'.
Я создал `admin.jsp`, но он игнорируется.
При этом если создать шаблон `admin.html` - все работает нормально.
Но мне это не подходит. Нужен именно JSP!

Вот контроллер:

```java
@GetMapping("/admin")
public String userList(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("allUsers", userService.allUsers());
    return "admin";
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mysql.connetor.version>8.0.15</mysql.connetor.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.8.0</jsonwebtoken.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connetor.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON Web Token lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Что именно Вы имеете в виду? Вы про то что у Вас обрабатывается в качестве шаблона `admin.html`, а не `admin.jsp`? Или про то, что вы создали в шаблонах  `somename.jsp` и пытаетесь на нее перейти?

Comment: Приведите `pom.xml`, чтобы примерно понимать конфигурацию приложения.

Comment: не получается перейти на admin.jsp, хотя она создана в проекте и в контроллере в возвращаемом значении прописано название файла

Comment: @МихаилРебров в проекте создан файл admin.jsp, в контроллере возвращается название этого файла, но показывает ошибку 404, что страница не найдена. Если вместо jsp создать admin.html таких проблем нет

Comment: да конечно тут еще

Comment: вам принципиально использовать именно JSP, или вам все равно что использовать в качестве шаблонизатора? в зависимости от ответа мне просто придется на несколько вопросов отвечать. Если вкратце, то ваше приложение настроено на работу с другим шаблонизатором, поэтому оно никак не реагирует на jsp лежащие у вас в ресурсах.

Comment: да мне нужно именно jsp

Comment: Если принципиально, то мне нужно будет написать как все это дело перенастроить

Comment: ок.
тогда придется чуть подольше подождать с ответом ибо писать придется дольше

Comment: хорошо, подожду сколько нужно, большое спасибо)

Comment: я написал ответ. Попробуйте.

Comment: Я написал под ответом комментарий. Я освобожусь после 12 и посмотрю. Но если там что-то специфичное, то возможно мне понадобятся какие-то дополнительные сведения, ибо у меня все работает

Comment: а вы не могли бы на github проект выложить и приложить ссылку на него?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### В чем проблема?

Посмотрим на приложенный pom.xml
Там мы найдем следующую зависимость:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Данная зависимость подключает шаблонизатор Thymeleaf и настраивает Spring, на работу с ним, а не с JSP.
Поэтому шаблон `admin.html` обрабатывался, а `admin.jsp` - нет.
*(Thymeleaf хранит свои шаблоны в фйлах с расширением .html)*

В целом я советую не пугаться и не избегать его категорически.
Лично я уже давно использую его в проектах со Spring'ом и Spring уже давно его используют в качестве шаблонизатора по умолчанию.
Поэтому причин *"шарахаться"* от него я не вижу.

Подробнее о Thymeleaf можно узнать на официальном сайте:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/

#### Не отходя от pom.xml

Взглянем еще внимательнее на зависимости:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Я уже понял что Вы любите Lombok, но зачем его подключать 4 раза?
Не надо так делать.

Также у Вас дублируется зависимость `javax.validation:validation-api`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Настоятельно советую все дубли заблаговременно убрать, иначе потом вы рискуете нарваться на конфликт версий или логическую ошибку(будете думать что удалили или поправили зависимость - а на самом деле нет)

#### Как настроить Spring для работы с JSP

Для начала удалим зависимость Thymeleaf с настройками.
Для этого из pom.xml удаляем следующие строки:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Далее важно понимать, что jsp - это не скрипты и они не являются исполняемыми файлами.
JSP сначала транслируется в код сервлета, а потом уже выполняется.
Делается это с помощью компилятора JSP-страниц Jasper.

Второе, что стоит понять это то,что когда Вы пользуетесь JSP, вы используете не только Java-код внутри верстки (а это и есть дефолтный функционал JSP).

Чаще всего JSP используют совместно с **JSTL (JSP Standart Tag Library)**.
Это библиотека стандартных тегов JSP, которая упрощает создание шаблонов, вывод данных, позволяет с помощью тегов реализовывать условия, циклы и пр. функционал.

`<c:if ... ></c:if>` и др. оттуда.

И напоследок нужно понимать, что всего этого добра сейчас у вас нет.
Соответственно его нужно подключить.

Добавляем в `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Переимпортируем заново все зависимости в Maven.

Далее нам следует настроить `ViewResolver` (компонент, который отвечает за определение и нахождение наших шаблонов)
Для этого достаточно создать бин, возвращающий объект имплементирующий
интерфейс ViewResolver.

```java
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

Здесь все просто:

- Cоздаем объект
- Указываем ему путь к нахождению шаблонов (в моем случае /WEB-INF/jsp/)
- Указываем ему расширение (.jsp)
- Указываем ему тип шаблона(в данном случае JstlView)

Данный бин, для простоты, можно положить прямо в Application

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

При этом шаблоны у меня хранятся в `{{ PROJECT_ROOT }}/src/main/WEB-INF/jsp/`

```
src
 |-main
    |-java
    |   \ ...
    |-resources
    |   \ ...
    |-WEB-INF
       |-jsp
          |-admin.jsp
          |-...

          ^
         /
        /
    ВОТ ТУТ
```

В итоге все должно работать.

Comment: огромное спасибо, все теперь работает!

Comment: @mak, рад за вас) обращайтесь если что

Comment: к сожалению, оно все-таки не сработало. Все по пунктам, как вы описали, сделано (обновлённый pom.xml прекреплен).

Comment: @mak, если хотите - можете написать мне в телеграм(он указан в профиле) и там подробнее и оперативнее сможете объяснить что не так